# I want to replace the elements of 'job title' (column of my dataset) having count less than 20 with 'others'

Tags: r

```
total_count = table(data_file$job_title)
count_index = which(total_count < 20)


fxn  <- function(x){
if (x %in% count_index)
      {
       others
    } 
else
  {
    x 
  }
}

apply(X = data_file, MARGIN =  1, FUN = fxn)
```

It gives me error :

```
#> the condition has length > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `forcats::fct_lump_min()`:

```r
forcats::fct_lump_min(c("A", "A", "B", "C"), 2)
#> [1] A     A     Other Other
#> Levels: A Other
```